# ESLint not able to detect certain modules while using `webpack` as `import/resolver`

Tags: javascript, webpack, eslint, eslint-plugin-import

I'm using Webpack in my project as well as ESLint. I've installed `eslint-plugin-import` and `eslint-import-resolver-webpack` to help ESLint understand some `resolve.aliases` used in the project (As is alluded to [here][1]). I'm also using `react-hook-form` as well as `react`.

The issue is when I try to [import][2] `react-hook-form`, ESLint tells me it's `Unable to resolve path to module 'react-hook-form'. eslint(import/no-unresolved)`. This doesn't happen with `react`. Here's a minimum, reproducible example (https://github.com/nishnat-rishi/min-repro).

In my actual project, the problematic `node_modules` are:

- `react-hook-form`
- `@headlessui/react`

and the working ones are:

- `@heroicons/react`
- `react`
- `react-dom`
- `react-router-dom`

I've already tried:

- Adding `{... resolve: { modules: ["node_modules"] } ... }` in `webpack.config.js`. Nothing changes with this, same error. I've also tried the following variants:

  ```
  ... modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules")]
  ... modules: [path.resolve(__dirname)]
  ```
- Adding `{... resolve: { mainFields: ["browser", "module", "main"] } ... }` in `webpack.config.js`. Nothing changes with this, same error. I also shifted around the three `mainFields` entries to no avail.

What am I missing / getting wrong?

Comment: Please don't add answers in a question. Feel free to post an answer if you've managed to solve the question yourself

Answer (score 1):

I needed to use both resolvers in my `.eslintrc`:

```
"import/resolver": {
  "node": {},
  "webpack": {}
}
```

Comment: Do you know why though? I expected `resolve: { modules: ["node_modules"]` in the Webpack config to cover this, too, since we are telling ESLint to use that.